# Diferencia entre includes() y match() javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Hola queria saber cual es la diferencia en la comparacion de strings entre includes() y match()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente la diferencia principal es que [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) te devuelve si una cadena está dentro de otra, mediante `true` o `false`, y [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match) te devuelve todas las ocurrencias que haya dentro de una cadena teniendo en cuenta una expresión regular (regex).

Te dejo un ejemplo muy básico con los dos casos en el que se puede ver fácilmente y en los cuales busco la palabra "prueba" dentro de la cadena:

```js
var cadena = "Esto es una prueba, para ver si prueba está dentro de la cadena.";
var expresion = /prueba/gi;
var coincidencias = cadena.match(expresion);
var incluida = cadena.includes("prueba");

console.log("Resultado con match:");
console.log(coincidencias);

console.log("Resultado con includes");
console.log(incluida);
```

Answer (score 2):

ambas realizan búsqueda de de texto dentro de una cadena la gran diferencia es que `Include()` realiza la búsqueda dentro de la otra cadena y devuelve verdadero o falso si esta encuentra coincidencia.

```
"Hola soy Ramiro".Include("ramiro") *//Esto devolverá falso debido a que Include() es "case sensitive"*  
"Hola soy Ramiro".Include("Ramiro") *//Esto devolverá Verdadero*
```

Ahora con el `Match()` realiza una búsqueda dentro de la cadena, pero esta utiliza expresiones regulares para realizar su función dando como resultado elementos que coincidan con la expresión.

```
"Hola soy Ramiro".Match(/ram/) *//Esto no devuelve nada porque está en "case sensitive"*  
"Hola soy Ramiro".Match(/ram/i) *//Esto devuelve "Ram" porque se indica que va a realizar coincidencias entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.*
```

Para mayor información de expresiones regulares:
[JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)
[JavaScript RegExp Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Include es para ver si la variable contiene la variable/palabra que se le está pasando y match mira las veces que se incluye esa palabra dentro de la variable

Answer (score 0):

**includes()** verifica que una cadena de string o un objeto contiene una palabra en especifico

[Include()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

**match()** retorna todas las coincidencias de una palabra de un string u objeto

[Match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)